# Forming a tournament table with LINQ (Fixture List)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, algorithm

I have an array of players (string[]) and now I need to get an array of pairs representing games (playerN-playerM) to orginize tournament table like at this picture:
[image]

The desired end result is to generate a fixture list with all the games the need to be played.

How can I do this with LINQ in efficient way?

UPDATED:
A-B, A-C, A-D is not correct - games should be able to run in parallel.
**I need result in the same order as at the picture**

Comment: Why LINQ? Its not the sort of set-based operation thats well suited to enumeration IMO

Comment: You should define better defined rules for sorting.

Comment: Do you always have an even number of players?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code can be used to generate a fixture list for a collection of teams to ensure that each time plays all other teams in 1 home and 1 away match.

The code is a bit long winded but it does work by providing you with a list in the order you have specified.

The code can probably be optimised but at the moment this is how it has come from my head.

**NOTE**: The resulting list will contain both Home and Away fixture, which based on your grid will be what you need to do anyway.

```
    class Fixture
    {
        public string Home { get; set; }
        public string Away { get; set; }
    }

    void CallCode()
    {
        string players = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
        List<Fixture> fixtures = CalculateFixtures(players);
    }

    List<Fixture> CalculateFixtures(string[] players)
    {
        //create a list of all possible fixtures (order not important)
        List<Fixture> fixtures = new List<Fixture>();
        for (int i = 0; i < players.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < players.Length; j++)
            {
                if (players[i] != players[j])
                {
                    fixtures.Add(new Fixture() { Home = players[i], Away = players[j] });
                }
            }
        }

        fixtures.Reverse();//reverse the fixture list as we are going to remove element from this and will therefore have to start at the end

        //calculate the number of game weeks and the number of games per week
        int gameweeks = (players.Length - 1) * 2;
        int gamesPerWeek = gameweeks / 2;

        List<Fixture> sortedFixtures = new List<Fixture>();

        //foreach game week get all available fixture for that week and add to sorted list
        for (int i = 0; i < gameweeks; i++)
        {
            sortedFixtures.AddRange(TakeUnique(fixtures, gamesPerWeek));
        }

        return sortedFixtures;
    }

    List<Fixture> TakeUnique(List<Fixture> fixtures, int gamesPerWeek)
    {
        List<Fixture> result = new List<Fixture>();

        //pull enough fixture to cater for the number of game to play
        for (int i = 0; i < gamesPerWeek; i++)
        {
            //loop all fixture to find an unused set of teams
            for (int j = fixtures.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                //check to see if any teams in current fixtue have already been used this game week and ignore if they have
                if (!result.Any(r => r.Home == fixtures[j].Home || r.Away == fixtures[j].Home || r.Home == fixtures[j].Away || r.Away == fixtures[j].Away))
                {
                    //teams not yet used
                    result.Add(fixtures[j]);
                    fixtures.RemoveAt(j);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: it will generates A-B, A-C, A-D - not the same result as I expect :(

Comment: @Nagg: I have added a working solution but it is not pretty at the minute!

Answer (score 4):

```
var games = players.SelectMany((player1, index) => 
    players.Skip(index + 1).
    Select(player2 => new {Player1 = player1, Player2 = player2}));
```

That should do it...

Comment: No, it generates A-B, A-C, A-D - not the same as at picture :(

Comment: @Nagg, it generates the same games but in a different order, do you want them in this exact order?

Comment: @nagg : order was not mentioned in your original question

Comment: @Nagg: if the ordering is so important to you, why don't you specify the required ordering? It isn't apparent from the question

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice that order is important, sorry, but it is.

Comment: @Nagg, OK so what's the logic behind the order?

Comment: @vc 74 I dont know :( I suppose it is a known game tournament tables forming alghorithm.

Comment: @Nagg, I'm afraid unless you can express the algorithm in simple and logical terms it will be hard to implement this logic...

Comment: @Nagg, what would be the order if there were 5 players?

Answer (score 1):

The implementation I really wanted:

```
public static List<List<Tuple<string, string>>> ListMatches(List<string> listTeam)
{
    var result = new List<List<Tuple<string, string>>>();

    int numDays = (listTeam.Count - 1);
    int halfSize = listTeam.Count / 2;
    var teams = new List<string>();
    teams.AddRange(listTeam.Skip(halfSize).Take(halfSize));
    teams.AddRange(listTeam.Skip(1).Take(halfSize - 1).ToArray().Reverse());
    int teamsSize = teams.Count;

    for (int day = 0; day < numDays; day++)
    {
        var round = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
        int teamIdx = day % teamsSize;
        round.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(teams[teamIdx], listTeam[0]));

        for (int idx = 1; idx < halfSize; idx++)
        {
            int firstTeam = (day + idx) % teamsSize;
            int secondTeam = (day + teamsSize - idx) % teamsSize;

            round.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(teams[firstTeam], teams[secondTeam]));
        }
        result.Add(round);
    }
    return result;
}
```