# "Match making" algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm, match, matching

For one project, I need to compute matchs planning between several teams.

Requirement:

- I've a pair number of teams
- All teams have to play against every other team once(and only once)
- All team plays at the same time

E.g.
With 4teams(A,B, C and D), I would like to be able to compute this:

**Round 1**

- A vs B
- C vs D

**Round 2**

- A vs D
- B vs C

**Round 3**

- A vs C
- B vs D

The problem is that, there is some choice in round X which will make impossible any match in round X+1(teams have already played against other teams).

I think I can use some backtracking technique, but I'm searching if there is an algorithm for this?

This will be implemented in c#.

Have you any idea about how to do this?

Comment: Does it need to be random or some arbitrary order is OK?

Comment: No random needed, just need to have all teams playing against all other teams(but random is ok too)

Comment: Can't you then just iterate each round with all teams, and if a team `i` is unassigned yet in round `j` `assign(team[i],team[(i+j) % team.Length])`?

Comment: @amit it won't work. Try it with 6 teams. Second step will be invalid.

Comment: @amit Yes, I already tried that, but like Matzi said, we fastly becomes in impossible solution

Comment: Yeap, sorry - got confused.:|

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7838168/880990

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I took a look, but it seems it doesn't handle the important notion of "round". My problem isn't to find combination, it's to have all teams playing at every round

Comment: Actually the answer is in the link @OlivierJacot-Descombes provided. If you look at this answer, the notion of rounds is represented by List<Tuple> (where Tuple is a Match): http://stackoverflow.com/a/7848715/390819

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try round-robin. This is a simple scheduling algorithm to share timeslots among processes, but this problem reminds me it somehow.

**EDIT**

Now here is an implementation of [Round-robin tournament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament). If we have ODD number of teams, we must insert a dummy team, otherwise there would be a team without opponent. As number of rounds are EVEN, number of total rounds are (NumberOfTeams-1). At the very beginning we set-up the first round:

A B C D E F G H

H G F E D C B A

So, Team A - H, Team B - G, etc.

From now, we keep one team fixed, for instance A. Then we shift A_Side teams from the 2nd position to the right. The last team will come into position 2. ( A B C D E F G H will be A H B C D E F G). See rotate_A_side() recursive method (just for fun).

The half of the B_Sides are shifted left. This will make H G F E D - G F E D.

As team selection is symmetric (A plays with H, then H plays wiht A), the upper half of B_Side is the reverse copy of the A_Side low part teams. So, D C B A will be C B H A). See rotate_B_side().

So, Round 2 is:

**A** H B C D E F G

G F E D *C B H A*

To give all rounds, simply repeat the aforementioned shifting steps. See NextRound()

Here is a c# class which implements the algorithm:

```
    class Teams
{
    private int[] A_Side;
    private int[] B_Side;
    public int[,] PlayingCounter;
    public int RoundCounter = 1;
    public bool DummyTeam = false;                 // ODD number of teams -> one team will no be able to play.

    public bool NextRoundExists
    {
        get
        {
            return (RoundCounter < B_Side.Length-1);

        }
    }
    public Teams(int NumberOfTeams)
    {
        if (NumberOfTeams % 2 != 0)
        {
            NumberOfTeams++; DummyTeam = true;
        }
        A_Side = new int[NumberOfTeams];
        B_Side = new int[NumberOfTeams];
        PlayingCounter = new int[NumberOfTeams,NumberOfTeams];     // Counting to see if alg is correct
        int x,y;
        for (x=0; x<NumberOfTeams; x++) 
        {
            A_Side[x] = x + 1;                  
            B_Side[NumberOfTeams-x-1]=x+1; 
            for (y=0;y<NumberOfTeams;y++) 
            {
                PlayingCounter[x,y] = 0;
            }

        }

    }

    private void rotate_A_Side(int AtPos)
    {
        if (AtPos == 1)
        {
            int iO = A_Side[A_Side.Length - 1];
            rotate_A_Side(AtPos+1);
            A_Side[1] = iO;
        }
        else 
        {
            if (AtPos < A_Side.Length - 1) { rotate_A_Side(AtPos + 1); }
            A_Side[AtPos] = A_Side[AtPos - 1];
        }
    }
    public void rotate_B_Side()
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i<B_Side.Length/2 ; i++)
        {
            B_Side[i] = B_Side[i + 1];
        }
        for (i = B_Side.Length / 2; i < B_Side.Length; i++)
        {
            B_Side[i] = A_Side[B_Side.Length/2 - (i -B_Side.Length/2 + 1) ];
        }

    }
    public bool NextRound()
    {
        if (NextRoundExists)
        {
            RoundCounter++;         // Next round
            rotate_A_Side(1);       // A side rotation
            rotate_B_Side();        // B side rotation
            LogRound();             // Update counters
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
    public void LogRound()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < A_Side.Length; x++)
        {
            PlayingCounter[A_Side[x]-1, B_Side[x]-1]++;
            PlayingCounter[B_Side[x]-1, A_Side[x]-1]++;
        }
    }
    public string GetCounters()
    {
        string return_value = "";

        for (int y = 0; y < A_Side.Length; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < A_Side.Length; x++)
            {
                return_value += String.Format(" {0:D3}", PlayingCounter[y, x]);
            }
            return_value += System.Environment.NewLine;
        }
        return return_value;
    }

    public string GetCurrentRound()
    {
        string Round = "Round #" + RoundCounter.ToString() + " ";
        for (int x = 0; x < B_Side.Length; x++)
        {
            Round += String.Format("Team {0} - Team {1};", A_Side[x], B_Side[x]);
        }
        return Round;
    }

}
```

From your code, you can use it like:

```
Teams Rounds = new Teams(22);
if (Rounds.DummyTeam) { 
       // Anything to do if nober of teams is odd?
}
Rounds.LogRound();    // DEBUG - you can check number of matches ;-)
while (Rounds.NextRoundExists)     // While we have next round...
 {
   Rounds.NextRound();             // ... generate the next 
                                   //     round (team assignment)
   // Your can tack using: Rounds.GetCurrentRound()
 }
// If you want to see the number of matches, call Rounds.GetCounters();
```

6 Teams gave me the following output:

Round #1 A-F ; B-E ; C-D ; D-C ; E-B ; F-A ;

Round #2 A-E ; F-D ; B-C ; C-B ; D-F ; E-A ;

Round #3 A-D ; E-C ; F-B ; B-F ; C-E ; D-A ;

Round #4 A-C ; D-B ; E-F ; F-E ; B-D ; C-A ;

Round #5 A-B ; C-F ; D-E ; E-D ; F-C ; B-A ;

*I replaced Team 1 with A, etc.*

rotate_B_Side() should be refined, this is a quick approach.

Comment: I like this approach, I will try it this evening :). My next step is to handle "odd" number of team(by having one team resting). Do you think that your "dummy" team can be this "resting" place ?

Comment: Yes, "dummy" stands for resting. The bool property will tell you if the very last team is the resting one. But it is automatically assigned - see constructor.

Comment: If you set number of teams to an odd number, constructor will increase it to even, and set bool to true. Then you know, the very last team is a resting team to its opponent.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the answer is in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7838168/390819) [Olivier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/880990/olivier-jacot-descombes) provided in the comments. More specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7848715/390819).

And it does handle the notion of Round, except it's not very obvious. In that code a `Tuple<string, string>` represents a match (an item containing two team names) and a `List<Tuple<string, string>>` represents a round (collection of Matches).

The code returns a collection of Rounds in the form of a `List<List<Tuple<string, string>>>`.

I refactored the code a bit so that the notions of `Match` and `Round` would be more obvious in the code.

Here are the `Match` and `Round` classes:

```
public class Match
{
    public string Team1 { get; set; }
    public string Team2 { get; set; }

    public Match(string team1, string team2)
    {
        Team1 = team1;
        Team2 = team2;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} vs {1}", Team1, Team2);
    }
}

public class Round
{
    public List<Match> Matches { get; private set; }

    public Round()
    {
        Matches = new List<Match>();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Matches) + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

And here is the code that does the magic (credits go to [Nagg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298088/nagg)):

```
public static List<Round> ComputeFixtures(List<string> listTeam)
{
    var result = new List<Round>();

    var numberOfRounds = (listTeam.Count - 1);
    var numberOfMatchesInARound = listTeam.Count / 2;

    var teams = new List<string>();

    teams.AddRange(listTeam.Skip(numberOfMatchesInARound).Take(numberOfMatchesInARound));
    teams.AddRange(listTeam.Skip(1).Take(numberOfMatchesInARound - 1).ToArray().Reverse());

    var numberOfTeams = teams.Count;

    for (var roundNumber = 0; roundNumber < numberOfRounds; roundNumber++)
    {
        var round = new Round();
        var teamIdx = roundNumber % numberOfTeams;

        round.Matches.Add(new Match(teams[teamIdx], listTeam[0]));

        for (var idx = 1; idx < numberOfMatchesInARound; idx++)
        {
            var firstTeamIndex = (roundNumber + idx) % numberOfTeams;
            var secondTeamIndex = (roundNumber + numberOfTeams - idx) % numberOfTeams;

            round.Matches.Add(new Match(teams[firstTeamIndex], teams[secondTeamIndex]));
        }

        result.Add(round);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here are some online running samples for this code:

- for four teams: http://ideone.com/bTfld
- for six teams: http://ideone.com/fw6wE
- for twelve teams: http://ideone.com/peIAI

Answer (score 2):

I think you are taking this the wrong way. 
Rather than computing on each round the pairing based on the previous round, I would start by making all the possible pairing using a simple double for loop, then randomly distribute the games by rounds.

Since every player will play exactly the same number of games, such distribution must exist.

Comment: But, using a simple random distribution isn't enought, because in all match possibility we have, we cannot make one team playing two match at the same time. And if we don't have a defined way to know which combination we should use, we will certainly go into this situation(I got it when trying with paper)

Comment: Here are two ideas, first keep track of all the players that have played in the current round on a boolean array. Second, on each round, sort the players by their possible opponents. This way, if at some point, a player x must play against a player y, this pairing will be found first. I'll write an algorithm for this. Hope I'm not wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

My quick go at it, using no-brainer method

1. generate all possible games
2. allocate games to rounds based on team availabibity

This result in a distribution of games which seem a little "stiff".

```
schedule_tournament(new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" });
schedule_tournament(new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D", });
schedule_tournament(new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" });
schedule_tournament(new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" });
schedule_tournament(new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" });
...

private void schedule_tournament(List<string> teams)
{            
    List<string> games = new List<string>();
    List<string> rounds = new List<string>();

    // get all possible games
    for (int i = 0; i < teams.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < teams.Count; j++)
        {
            string game_name = string.Format("{0}{1}", teams[i], teams[j]);
            if (!games.Contains(game_name)) games.Add(game_name);
        }
    }

    // allocate games to rounds
    for (int i = 0; i < games.Count; i++)
    {
        bool allocated = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < rounds.Count; j++)
        {
            string team_1 = games[i].Substring(0, 1);
            string team_2 = games[i].Substring(1, 1);
            if (!rounds[j].Contains(team_1) && !rounds[j].Contains(team_2))
            {
                rounds[j] += " - " + games[i];
                allocated = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!allocated)
        {
            rounds.Add(games[i]);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0} teams, play {1} games in {2} rounds", teams.Count, games.Count, rounds.Count);
    for (int i = 0; i < rounds.Count; i++) Console.WriteLine("Round {0}: {1}", i + 1, rounds[i]);
}
```

the output of this is:

```
3 teams, play 3 games in 3 rounds
Round 1: AB
Round 2: AC
Round 3: BC
4 teams, play 6 games in 3 rounds
Round 1: AB - CD
Round 2: AC - BD
Round 3: AD - BC
5 teams, play 10 games in 7 rounds
Round 1: AB - CD
Round 2: AC - BD
Round 3: AD - BC
Round 4: AE
Round 5: BE
Round 6: CE
Round 7: DE
6 teams, play 15 games in 7 rounds
Round 1: AB - CD - EF
Round 2: AC - BD
Round 3: AD - BC
Round 4: AE - BF
Round 5: AF - BE
Round 6: CE - DF
Round 7: CF - DE
7 teams, play 21 games in 7 rounds
Round 1: AB - CD - EF
Round 2: AC - BD - EG
Round 3: AD - BC - FG
Round 4: AE - BF - CG
Round 5: AF - BE - DG
Round 6: AG - CE - DF
Round 7: BG - CF - DE
```