# Fixture Creating

Tags: c#, algorithm

Going from the last post on [Forming a tournament table with LINQ (Fixture List)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838168/forming-a-tournament-table-with-linq-fixture-list?lq=1)

When adding a List of numbers e.g.

```
var fixture = ListMatches(new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16" });
```

When I run the code, number 1 is always 2nd. e.g.

```
Round 1
9 v 1

Round 2
10 v 1

Round 3
11 v 1
```

I'm struggling to figure out how I would be able to amend the code so that each "Round" the numbers will alternate from "Home" and "Away". So if 1 was 2nd, on the next round it would be 1st. If 16 was 1st in Round 1, it would be 2nd, away, in Round 2.

```
Round 1
9 v 1

Round 2
1 v 10

Round 3
11 v 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a stupid suggestion, but you could switch the order of games played on even-numbered rounds.

```
List<List<Tuple<string, string>>> fixture = 
  ListMatches(new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16" });

bool switchOrder = false;
foreach (round in fixture)
{
  if (switchOrder)
  {
     foreach (var tuple in round)
     {
         string temp = tuple.Item1;
         tuple.Item1 = tuple.Item2;
         tuple.Item2 = temp;
     }
  }
  switchOrder = !switchOrder
}
```

Comment: Very true! Many thanks! No idea why I didn't think of that! :)